# How would one describe tightly pulling on your coat to feel warmer in winters?

Tags: phrase-requests

It's like when you try to button up your shirt but pull the shirt too far- such that your back completely hugs your shirt and there is no space between your back and the shirt, or when you have a shirt that is one or two sizes smaller, but for coats, and you are doing it intentionally to try and feel warmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word I would use is [**snug**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snug), either as a verb or an adjective:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *intransitive verb*
> : SNUGGLE, NESTLE
> // *snug* down for bed
>
> *transitive verb*
> **1** : to cause to fit closely
> **2** : to make snug
> **4** : to secure by fastening or lashing down
>
> adjective
> **1 c** : fitting closely and comfortably
>        // a *snug* coat
> **2 a** : enjoying or affording warm secure shelter or cover and opportunity for ease and contentment
>        // a *snug* cottage
>        // a *snug* haven

So:

- I *snugged* my coat around me.
- My coat was *snug* and warm.